# JS TypeWriter Scrolling Effect in Textarea: Scrolling-Up, Auto-Expanding Text Area With Maximum Height Limit

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, autogrow

I have a text area for a chatbot. when the text area gets filled it wants to auto expand upwards and max height it can expand should be 100px. Is there anyway to do this?

```css
.textbox-1{
  padding-top:100px;
  }
```

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <div class="text-center textbox-1">
      <input class="filter-searchbox py-2" type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search" />
     </div>
```

Comment: Try this component: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-textarea-autosize

Comment: Hey, let me know if my answer helped at all, thanks!

Comment: @HoldOffHunger Hey, Thanks! It worked perfectly, but instead of expanding downwards, i want it upwards..

Comment: @SreehariAvikkal I think I made the adjustments necessary, take a look below, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [**`onInput`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput) to resize the input field based on the [**`scrollHeight`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) attribute...

> The scrollHeight value is equal to the minimum height the element would require in order to fit all the content in the viewport without using a vertical scrollbar. (Source: Above-linked MDN Webdocs.)

So, if the `scrollHeight` is above the max, we set the height to max, otherwise, we set the height to `scrollHeight`.

**Note**: I changed it to a `textarea` since that works more naturally with text flowing from top to bottom (whereas an input element doesn't work naturally with that).

```js
const tx = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
const maxheight = 100;
const normalheight = window.getComputedStyle(tx[0]).getPropertyValue('height').replace("px", "");
for (let i = 0; i < tx.length; i++) {
  tx[i].setAttribute("style", "margin-top:-3px;" + "height:" + (tx[i].scrollHeight > maxheight ? maxheight : tx[i].scrollHeight) + "px;overflow-y:hidden;");
  tx[i].addEventListener("input", OnInput, false);
}

function OnInput() {
  this.style.marginTop = (normalheight - this.style.height.replace("px", "")) + "px";
  this.style.height = "auto";
  this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight > maxheight ? maxheight : this.scrollHeight) + "px";
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center textbox-1">
 <textarea rows="1"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow. This works perfectly ! I think i should find some way to avoid that blinking when extra row is added. Thanks bud